# How can I call CanExecute from an event to disable the Command?

Tags: wpf, command

I have a command "ShowDataCommand" with a `CanExecute` method.

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return _someFacade.CanCommandEnable();
}
```

When I launch my application, `CanExecute` gets called and depending on the value returned from facade, it either
enables or disables the command.

Now new requirement is that, there is a button in the main page. When user clicks that button a dialog opens
and till the time dialog is open the "ShowDataCommand" should be disable.

There is already an event fired when dialog is open and when dialog is closed.  I have subscribed the event in the command.
The event fires with appropriate true and false value.

Now I don't know how can I disable the Command from this event? Can I somehow raise `CanExecute` with this new value?

Comment: Give your command class a method called `RaiseCanExecute()` which raises the command object's `CanExecute` event. Then anybody who has subscribed to that event will update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the `CanExecute` method of your command to get called again by raising the `CanExecuteChanged` event.

Most `ICommand` implementations have a method for raising this event so if you are using your own implementation you could add a method to your class and call it whenever you want to "refresh" the command, for example when your button is clicked:

```
public class YourCommandClass : ICommand
{
    ...
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() //<-- call this method
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Please refer to the `RelayCommand` class in `MvvmLight` for an example of an `ICommand` implementation: https://github.com/paulcbetts/mvvmlight/blob/dce4e748c538ed4e5f5a0ebbfee0f54856f52dc6/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/Command/RelayCommand.cs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I raise it with bool value. I mean to enable or disable when an event fires -  private void OnDialogStateChanged(bool isDialogOpen)
        {
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged(isDialogOpen);
        }

Comment: You don't. You should set        _someFacade.CanCommandEnable and make sure that it returns true or false when the command is refreshed. The CanExecute method should contain your logic to enable/disable the command.

Comment: any idea why CanExecuteChanged is always null for me? Thanks